# Displaying posts from today forward

Tags: wordpress

I have a site that was developed by the developer before me and I am the lucky one that gets to try to figure out how to resolve his issues.

I am currently trying to display events from today forward. This is a CPT and has custom fields. I am not sure if I have just looked at this code for to long and am just missing the answer or what but I just cannot see where I am going wrong.

Not only am I not getting ANY results I am getting "Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object" in my "Dates:" section.

I have read and tried countless possibilities without success. I am hoping that a fresh pair of eyes can help me out.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

$today = current_time('Ymd');
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'posts_events',
    'post_status' => 'publish', 
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'start_date',
            'compare' => '>=',
            'value' => $today,
        )
    ),
    'meta_key' => 'start_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 ));
?>
<!-- CONTENT STARTS -->
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="container_16" id="event-list_container">
    <div class="col_14 prefix_1">
        <?php
            $taxonomy     = 'sbts';
            $orderby      = 'name';
            $show_count   = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
            $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
            $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
            $title        = '';
            $empty        = 0;

            $args = array(
                'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
                'orderby'      => $orderby,
                //'show_count'   => $show_count,
                //'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
                'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
                'title_li'     => $title,
                'hide_empty'   => $empty

            );
        ?>
        <ul class="taxonomy-list-links">
            <?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>
        </ul>
    </div>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <div class="container_14 prefix_1 suffix_1 event-list"> 
        <?php $background_image = MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_id(get_post_type(), 'event-thumb', $post->ID); $background_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $background_image,'event-thumb' ); ?>
        <div class="col_5 event-photo" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $background_image[0]; ?>);"></div>
        <div class="col_8 prefix_5 event-content">
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?><?php if($today > get_field('end_date')) echo  '</h2><p>Past Event</p>'; ?>
            <?php $firm = get_field('host_firm'); ?>
            <h3>Member Host Firm: <span class="event-p"><?php echo $firm[0]->post_title; ?></span></h3>     
            <h3>Location: <span class="event-p"><?php echo get_field('event_location'); ?></span></h3>  
            <h3>Dates: <span class="event-p"><?php $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', get_field('start_date')); echo $date->format('M j, Y'); ?> - <?php $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', get_field('end_date')); echo $date->format('M j, Y'); ?></span></h3>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="button_gray">Event Details</a>
        </div>

    </div>  
    <?php endwhile; ?>  
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container_16 nested" id="page-navigation_container">
            <div class="col_14 gap prefix_1" id="page-navigation"><?php theme_pagination(); ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>
<!-- CONTENT STOPS  -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: you have $args twice try renaming it unless you want the second $args to be used in the query.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a new query with the args you want to pass for the loop:

[Check the wp codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

```
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: This won't fix everything that is wrong, but it will start you in the right direction.

Comment: I had just caught the duplicated name issue, got that fixed and got the dates issue resolved but still no results at all.